# Could not cast value of type 'NSTableCellView' to 'NSTableViewTest'

Tags: swift, nstableview

I'm trying to set up a custom class for an NSTableView and seem to be almost there with it.

When I run this code I get an error message : Could not cast value of type 'NSTableCellView' (0x7fff7a859af0) to 'NSTableViewTest.MyCellView' (0x10001e480) in the line "let cell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(tableColumn!.identifier, owner: self)  as! MyCellView!"

```
import Cocoa

class Table1: NSTableView, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate
{

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect)
    {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
    }

    func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int
    {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, heightOfRow row: Int) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 25
    }

    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?
    {
        let cell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(tableColumn!.identifier, owner: self)  as! MyCellView!
        return cell
    }

}
```

with my cell class defined as :

```
import Cocoa

class MyCellView: NSView 
{
    @IBOutlet weak var itemName: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemDescription: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemImage: NSImageView!

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the identifier you use. `tableColumn!.identifier` This is a column's identifier, but you want to generate a NSView for a cell view.

```
   1. Go to the storyboard and select a cell view
   2. associate it with MyCellView (set it in the identity inspector)
   3. specify an identifier in the storyboard (set it in the identity inspector)
   4. Modify the identifier in the code. It should be some string like "MyCellView"
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also need to register the nib file in the ViewController which can be done in `viewDidLoad()`.

```
let nib = NSNib(nibNamed: "MyCellView", bundle: Bundle.main)
myTableView.register(nib!, forIdentifier: "MyCellView")
```

Answer (score 1):

tableColumn!.identifier should be a String , eg. "cell".
The String , after selecting the Prototype cell in the Storyboard, should match the identifier.

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?
{
    let cell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("cell", owner: self)  as! MyCellView!
    return cell
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `MyCellView` class is of `NSView`, change it to be of type `NSTableCellView`, as you cant cast `NSView` to be a `NSTableCellView`.

I hope that helped you!